# Picture and text side by side by using html formatting

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Picture and text side by side by using html formatting works when using Outlook 2010.  I just inserted the picture from file, inserted a text block and pasted words.

On the receiving end, the email showed the picture above the text in line.

How can I prevent this formatting change on the recipient's e-mail client?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I prevent this formatting change on the recipient's e-mail client?

By hacking the client's network and forcing their client configuration to be what you want it to be.

Short of that, you can't.

Just as you have no control over whether my web browser uses the wrong character set encoding, or if my graphics card invert the colors, or if I have an online translator automatically set to try to translate your post into a homoerotic haiku in ancient Greek, you have no control over any other settings I (or anyone else) might have in my mail client either.